# Use __attribute__((objc_requires_super)) with protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have something like this:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)oneMethod;

@end
```

.

```
@interface BaseClassWithProtocol : NSObject <MyProtocol>

@end
```

.

```
@interface ChildClassWithProtocol : BaseClassWithProtocol

@end
```

`BaseClassWithProtocol` has implemented `oneMethod`, and I want to show warning if `ChildClassWithProtocol` doesn't call super in its `oneMethod` implementation.

But I don't know where should I write `__attribute__((objc_requires_super))`.

Writing it in **protocol** is not supported while redefining oneMethod in .h looks stupid.

So is there any standard way which can deal with the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The requirement to call super is imposed by `BaseClassWithProtocol`. It's not part of the protocol. Surely, some class could implement `MyProtocol` however it wants without that requirement being imposed. That's the nature of protocols. They impose interface, not implementation.

So, redeclaring the method in `BaseClassWithProtocol` with the attribute seems perfectly sensible to me. Not sure why it "looks stupid".

Comment: Thank you . 
Redeclaring oneMethod in .h doesn't override the interface, it just happen to be the same declaration as which declared in protocol. I don't know whether my understanding is correct. But what if those two methods declared in .h and protocol have the same name but different parameter type? This is why I think it stupid, because I don't know which one is the final declaration, and declaring twice seems verbose. However, it seems to be the only place I can put clang attribute, and I will take this.

Comment: But can you tell me whether swift protocol extension can do this(I know little about swift). Or can you tell me how to write a strict declaration with a class which has protocol and abstract class(not "abstract class" in other language, just means more abstract than its child and maybe not implement some of the methods) using macro/clang attribute/or anything else?

Comment: @Tepmnthar same name but different parameter type? This two methods will be regarded as two different methods as Objective-C doesn't have *Method Overloading*

Comment: If the methods declared in the .h file and the protocol have different parameter types, the compiled will complain. Yes, declaring the method twice is a bit verbose, but you're adding information in the second declaration, so that's to be expected. Can't answer your question about Swift. I don't understand what you're asking about a "strict declaration".

Answer (score 1):

Protocols aren't meant to give warnings for your diverse implementations. They only warn you whether you agree to include the required methods in your implementation or not. But how you implement the methods, that's up-to your **Base** class that adopts the protocol. That is, **you should have your necessary functionalities in your .h or .m files.**

Consider this way:

> You have a method in your protocol where you want to have a warning for the super calls. Now you adopt the protocol in a class which is the sub-class of NSObject. But the NSObject class doesn't conform to the protocol you are defining. Would you now supposed to get the warning for your class? **According to your requirements, you should get that warning.** But this isn't the case. You would practically never get that warning by this procedure.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. Just haven't seen method which declared twice in \@protocol and \@interface and feel a bit curious.